# how to position a draggable div on the top of td

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have a table with 2 columns, first for time and the second with `class='empty'` and another div with `class='interview'`, I want whenever the user drag and drop the div to align its position exactly on the top of the `td.empty` that was dropped over and to change the class of this td to `occupied`

here a sample of what I am doing:

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/skv9y1ef/1/)

Unfortunately, I am not able so far to let this to work, any help would be appreciated

Comment: Your fiddle is full of syntax errors... please fix such issues before posting questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery UI [`position()`](http://api.jqueryui.com/position/) method as shown below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.interview').draggable({
    cursor: 'move',
    revert: 'invalid',
  })
  $('.empty').droppable({
    drop: function(ev, ui) {
      $(this).removeClass('empty').addClass('occupied');
      ui.draggable.position({
        my: 'left top',
        at: 'left top',
        of: this
      });
    }
  })
})
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 1px solid #333;
}

table td {
  border: 1px solid #c1a1a1 !important;
}

table .time {
  width: 60px;
  font-family: 'Calibri'
}

table .empty {
  width: 180px;
}

.interview {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  background-color: e1a2c1;
  height: 35px;
  width: 180px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class='time'>09:00</td>
    <td class='empty'></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class='time'>10:00</td>
    <td class='empty'></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class='time'>11:00</td>
    <td class='empty'></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class='time'>12:00</td>
    <td class='empty'></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class='time'>13:00</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class='time'>14:00</td>
    <td class='empty'></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<div class='interview'>
  This test
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than positioning the draggable element on top of the `td`, I suggest appending the element when the drop event is fired on the droppable element:

[**Updated Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/a2rtapkr/)

```
$('.interview').draggable({
  cursor: 'move',
  revert: 'invalid',
  helper: 'clone'
})
$('.empty').droppable({
  tolerance: 'pointer',
  drop: function(event, ui) {
    ui.draggable.appendTo(this);
  }
});
```

Based on your comment below, if you want the element to span across multiple rows, you could add:

```
table .empty {
  position: relative;
}
table .empty .interview {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0;
}
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, it worked, but what if the interview was for 2 hours like from [10:00 - 12:00] for example?